# Get list of active connections from SSMS addin

Tags: c#, sql-server, plugins, ssms, add-in

I'm trying to get list of all active connections infos from SSMS addin.

I know that I can get connection like this:

```
UIConnectionInfo uiConnectionInfo = ServiceCache.ScriptFactory.CurrentlyActiveWndConnectionInfo.UIConnectionInfo;
```

The problem is that it only gives me connection info for currently active document. I have multiple connections in solution explorer and need to get them all.

Does anybody know a way to get list of all active connections infos?

Alternatively, is there is a way to access list of connection infos from registered servers, that would help too.

Thanks!

Comment: read that, maybe it will help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013.aspx

Comment: Can you just run the system procedure `sp_who2` ?

Comment: It's not about list of connections **to** sql server. It's about list of connections **from** ssms studio (i.e. client). Both sp_who2 and sys.dm_exec_sessions are server-wide. SSMS can be connected to multiple different servers at the same time.